# resource files in Haaf's game engine

Tags: visual-c++, game-engine, unzip

I'm working with a program that uses Haaf's game engine which uses resource files that are saved as a .nsf format. These files are actually just zip files with a folder hierarchy in them and a resources.nsr file which just has information about each file.

The resources.nsf file has folders and an .nsr file setup like this:

```
|_resource.nsf
 |_images
 ||-some .png files
 |_sounds
 ||-some sound files
 |-resource.nsr
```

The format of the .nsr file is as follows:

```
;TEXTURES-------------------------------------
Texture background
{
   filename = images\background.png
}
;---------------------------------------------
Texture a 
{
  filename = images\a.png
}
;---------------------------------------------
Texture b 
{
  filename = images\b.png
}
....more textures
;SPRITES--------------------------------------
Sprite backgroundSpr
{
  texture = background
  rect = 0, 0, 1024, 768
}
....more sprites
```

In the images folder I found a thumbs.db file, and when I opened it the first line had Mac OS X printed in it. I assume that the zip file originated on an OS X system.

I have tried zipping up a new resource file with 7zip and windows compression. The site for [Haaf's game engine](http://hge.relishgames.com/doc/index.html) recommends using pkzip, but that costs money now so I cannot obtain a copy of it.

Is there a way I can repack my resource file and have it work under Windows 7 x64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Winrar works if you compress it to a zip file, this will allow the game engine to use the resource files properly.